# How do I center a row of images?

Tags: html, css

English major here; I know practically *nothing* about coding, so please use VERY BASIC language. I need to know for my book publishing class website. I'm trying to align rows of images for our "Team Members" page. How do I do that? Below is the first row of images. Right now, they're shifted to the left.

```html
<div id="main" class="container">



  <!-- First Set -->
  <h3> Publishers </h3>
  <div class="box alt">
    <div class="row 50% uniform">
      <!-- % changes space between pictures -->
      <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Mike<br>Course Director</p></span></div>
      <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Mackenzie<br>Publisher</p></span></div>
      <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Liz<br>Associate Publisher</p></span></div>
      <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Mia<br>Publishing Assistant</p></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try `<style>.box { text-align: center; }</style>`

Comment: Please provide working code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<center>` tag to center anything...
Hope this helps...

```html
<h3> Publishers </h3>
<center>
        <div class="box alt">
            <div class="row"> <!-- % changes space between pictures -->
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/mike.JPG" alt="" /><p> Mike<br>Course Director</p></span></div>
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/mackenzie.JPG" alt="" /><p> Mackenzie<br>Publisher</p></span></div>
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/liz.JPG" alt="" /><p> Liz<br>Associate Publisher</p></span></div>
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/mia.JPG" alt="" /><p> Mia<br>Publishing Assistant</p></span></div>           
            </div>
            
        </div>
        </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

This is a severe problem with css that is resolved with flex

styles.css

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;     /* vertical centering   */
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal centering */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this to learn css.

```css
.row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3> Publishers </h3>
        <div class="box alt">
            <div class="row"> <!-- % changes space between pictures -->
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Mike<br>Course Director</p></span></div>
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Mackenzie<br>Publisher</p></span></div>
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Liz<br>Associate Publisher</p></span></div>
                <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="" /><p> Mia<br>Publishing Assistant</p></span></div>           
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as follows.

```
<!-- First Set -->
    <h3> Publishers </h3>
    <div class="box alt">
        <div class="row 50% uniform" style="left: 50%;position: absolute;> <!-- % changes space between pictures -->
            <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/mike.JPG" alt="" /><p> Mike<br>Course Director</p></span></div>
            <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/mackenzie.JPG" alt="" /><p> Mackenzie<br>Publisher</p></span></div>
            <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/liz.JPG" alt="" /><p> Liz<br>Associate Publisher</p></span></div>
            <div class="2u"><span class="image fit"><img src="images/headshots/mia.JPG" alt="" /><p> Mia<br>Publishing Assistant</p></span></div>           
        </div>
    </div>
```